# Vue3 call a components method from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to have a component call a function from another component but just from
inside the setup.
I've read this from vuemastery https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/understanding-vue-3-expose/
and I see that you can accomplish this like this:

```
 methods: {
    reset () {
      this.$refs.counter.reset()
    },
    terminate () {
      this.$refs.counter.terminate()
    }
  }
```

however, I don't have access to those methods inside the setup, and I also can't use this.$refs inside the setup. Is there a way I can do the same thing inside setup, or a way to access these methods inside the setup?

Those methods are undefined in setup, and I cannot access data setup from within those functions, and I cannot use $refs in setup.

The $refs is a very easy way to call a function from another component - but I can't seem to find a relatively easy way to do this with vue3 composition api - am I missing something?

Comment: So did you tried `expose: ['reset']` or the appropriate one you need to have access to?

Comment: The best way (for your development, including) use Composite API and provide/inject. https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

Comment: @kissu yeah so if I go `expose: ['reset']` then I would only have access to reset not to terminate from the methods option. However that's not really my question, When I go to call the reset or terminate (with or without exposing them) from setup they are undefined. And I can't access data from setup within those methods. So I need a way to either call those from setup or do the same thing in setup.

Comment: @Михаил Looks like that link is using options api with data - I need to use setup and composition api. it's using data and this which I can't use in composition api setup

Comment: i dont know much about expose, but when i encounter such case i use mixins

Comment: what mixins do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I figured it out https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs

If I go

```
<script>
 export default {
  setup(props) {
   const counter = ref(null);
   //now I have access to counter.value.reset after it's mounted
   counter.value.reset(); //does not work! it's null here
   onMounted(() => {
    counter.value.reset(); //here it works
   })
   //make sure to return counter in return
```

looks like there is an easy way to do this in setup just has a caveat

- you cant just call it right away because setup happens before mounted https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html

I am calling it on a trigger - so if someone selects something from a dropdown I am watching the v-model and am able to call it there no problem.
Thanks for all the input.
Putting this answer here in case anyone else needs to accomplish the same thing